# Detach Individual Settings/Properties Tabs as Small Windows?

Tags: interface, properties

Is there any way I can detach individual settings tabs to be their own windows in Blender 2.8 rather than it being stuck within the interface?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not a free solution, but you could do this with custom panels/menus via the Pie Edit addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/pie-menu-editor?ref=2 It has a lot of wonderful UI functionality.

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is non, as far as I know properties windows tabs are not detachable.

But nothing stops you from having multiple of them open. As a workaround just duplicate the window and change active tabs on each instance.

Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging from one of the corners to create a new secondary window and change tabs for each

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.

Comment: Welcome. Don't post thank you as a comment, if an answer helped you upvote it. If you feel it solved you problem consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new window by splitting the one on top, have that window be a properties window editor and set it to whatever section you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel then select duplicate area into new window. Of course after this you can merge the old panel with others in the main window, by right clicking on the separation line between them, and select join area.